# How to load the Test Data or Sample data for Shopizer?

Tags: java, shopizer

Is there any way by which I can use the Test Data or Sample data for Shopizer?
I have installed it successfully but now I want to add some products or contents to see actual functionality in general.

As I can see from documentation that we can load the Test Data in the initial startup, that will give an overview on how to configure an online store.
For this I have edited `sm-shop/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/shopizer-properties.xml`

```
<prop key="POPULATE_TEST_DATA">false</prop>
```

and modified above property key with TRUE.

but it not loading any test data. Am I doing it in wrong way?
or is there any other way to achieve this?

Also I want to know basic difference between "sm-core" and "sm-shop" packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps and I am sure you will be able to get test data.

1. Drop your schema and create it fresh.
2. in `shopizer-properties.xml`, set `<prop key="POPULATE_TEST_DATA">true</prop>`

This will be able to load test data in the initial startup.Regarding your second question

### sm-core

sm-core provides core functionality under Shopizer like

1. Model classes
2. Services
3. Util classes
4. Caching API
5. Integration points for Payment , Shipping etc

In short sm-core is providing core functionality required for any eCommerce store.

### sm-shop

`sm-shop` is providing common functionalists,controllers and API for a online store like

1. Shopping Cart
2. API/ functionality to use CMS for Shopizer
3. API/ functionality for Category / PDP etc.

`sm-core` used Services as well other integration points provided by `sm-core` as well it is dependent upon the model layer being used in `sm-core`

Comment: Great!!.. I am able to get Test data now.. Thanks :)

Comment: from where can I drop the schema, can please explain

Comment: @Hayaaziz: in DB.properties, set schema creation to create and it will always create schema fresh and populate test data

Comment: I comment mySQL, and uncomment H2 in database.properties, and this is what is written by default: db.jdbcUrl=jdbc\:h2\:file\:SALESMANAGER;AUTOCOMMIT=OFF;INIT\=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS SALESMANAGER ... so what should I modify?